# Entscheidungsproblem

Tags: math-history, mathematica, mathematicians

I'm trying to understand the problem proposed by David Hilbert in 1928. So, oversimplifying a bit, he was asking for an algorithm that, given a set of axioms, returns true/false if a statement input satisfies all of the above axioms?

E.G.
Axiom: Everyone called Gianni is a man
Input: Gianni is a woman
Output: false

Comment: Oversimplifying a bit, yes. Wikipedia article on it should be pretty helpful to you. The question you just asked is not good fit for math stackexchange, since it's not really clear what exactly you are asking about.

Comment: I needed also [this link](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gianni) to understand the question. I already failed with "Andrea" or "Simone".

Comment: Not exactly; "The [Entscheidungsproblem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entscheidungsproblem) asks for an algorithm that takes as input a statement of a first-order logic and answers "Yes" or "No" according to whether the statement is universally valid, i.e., valid in every structure." Equivalently, given a statement and a finite number of proper axioms (specific math axiom in addition to the logical axioms) answers "Yes" or "No" according to whether the statement is a consequence of the axioms.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm sorry if the question wasn't asked properly, I didn't really think it through. I thought that mathexchange was the right forum and I just wanted to know if I got the concept almost right